# Is there a way in Excel to deliver first instance of a number in a list of errors logical and number values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is the reverse 2 way lookup formula  that delivers column headers by matching  first instance of numbers beneath and getting colnum to index function.This formula works fine if there are no duplicate values

Sample data

| Pr/Mo | jan | feb | march | apr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pro1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 4 |
| Pro2 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 9 |
| Pro3 | 10 | 9 | 11 | 12 |

Formula:
$A$6 value is 9

```
=Index($B$1:$E$1),,Sum(if($B$2:$E$4=$A$6,(Column($B$1:$E$1)-Column($B$1))+1)
```

If function returns :
{False,False,False,False,False,False,False,3,False,1,False,False}

3 is recquired here which is first instance not 1 but how to using formula not VBA.

Comment: You'll have to provide a set of sample data and the result you're trying to achieve. I don't think there's enough information in your post to really determine what's going on.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use match (which is made to return the first matching value)

Comment: So how to do that.how match delivers first instance.

Comment: I have given sample data